# Conditionally show cells in a static cell tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a static table view set up in interface builder, but in some circumstances I don't want some cells to show. What's the best way to accomplish this with static cells? I'd really like to use static cells because a) it makes sense because there is no datasource, and b) I'm rendering my static views using IBDesignable/IBInspectable and would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the UITableViewDelegate method **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:** and return 0 for any row that you don't want to show.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 44.0;
    if (indexPath.row == /* a row you want to hide */) {
        rowHeight = 0.0;
    }
    return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: I had thought of doing it that way but there are some reasons I chose not to go with this: 

For one, I have alternating background colors; in willDisplay I set that background color based on indexPath.row % 2 - hiding the rows and not removing them breaks this functionality. Also, I have textfields in these rows and I chain the first responders - if the rows are still technically there, it will cause the hidden textfield to become first responder.